# PHP syntax error in function, don't know why

Tags: php

I'm getting a syntax error and I can't figure out why. "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' on line 6"

```
function ExtractCustomField($fieldName, $customFields) {
// $customFields might be an object, NULL, or an array.
$parsed = array();
if (is_array($customFields) == false && $customFields != null) {
$parsed = array($customFields);
} else (is_array($customFields)) {
$parsed = $customFields;
}

// loop through the fields and find the one we are looking for
$returnField = null;
foreach($field as $customFields) {
if ($field->Name == $fieldName) {
$returnField = $field;
break;
}
}

return $returnField
}
```

Comment: You’re missing a semicolon in the `return` statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forget to put semicolon after `$returnField`, also use elseif instead of else (else don't need any arguments). Use the code below

```
function ExtractCustomField($fieldName, $customFields) {
// $customFields might be an object, NULL, or an array.
$parsed = array();
if (is_array($customFields) == false && $customFields != null) {
$parsed = array($customFields);
} elseif (is_array($customFields)) {
$parsed = $customFields;
}

// loop through the fields and find the one we are looking for
$returnField = null;
foreach($field as $customFields) {
if ($field->Name == $fieldName) {
$returnField = $field;
break;
}
}

return $returnField;
}
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: Thanks, dumb mistake on my part.

Answer (score 0):

`else` doesn't take any expression after it. Either remove the expression or use `elseif` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You have missed semicolon in return

```
return $returnField;
}
```

Also Else condition `else (is_array($customFields))` format is wrong....else dont take any condition after it...You can use Elseif instead

Answer (score 0):

```
else (is_array($customFields)) {
```

Is invalid. Use either else if or remove the condition

Answer (score 0):

```
function ExtractCustomField($fieldName, $customFields) {
// $customFields might be an object, NULL, or an array.
$parsed = array();
if (is_array($customFields) == true && $customFields != null) {
$parsed = array($customFields);
} else {
$parsed = $customFields;
}

// loop through the fields and find the one we are looking for
$returnField = null;
foreach($field as $customFields) {
if ($field->Name == $fieldName) {
$returnField = $field;
break;
}
}

return $returnField;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It should else if(is_array($customFields)) or elseif(is_array($customFields))

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your function, i see there is supposed to be and elseif instead of else and in the foreach loop, the syntax in your code was wrong. I have also assumed that you will be using a single level associative array.

```
<?php
    function ExtractCustomField($fieldName, $customFields) {
            // $customFields might be an object, NULL, or an array.
            $parsed = array();
            if (is_array($customFields) == false && $customFields != null) {
                $parsed = array($customFields);
            } elseif (is_array($customFields)) {
                $parsed = $customFields;
            }

            // loop through the fields and find the one we are looking for
            $returnField = null;
            foreach($customFields as $field) {
                if ($field == $fieldName) {
                    $returnField = $field;
                    break;
                }
            }
            return $returnField;
        }

        echo ExtractCustomField('name', array('name','emial','mobile','password'));
?>
```